# Customize grouped rows in v-data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

I use `v-data-table` with grouped rows: https://codepen.io/jangaraj/pen/zYqOwBj?editors=1010

I would like to show also item count for each category, e.g. `category: Candy (3 items in the group)`.
Is there any slot for this kind of customization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the `group.header` slot...

```
 <template v-slot:group.header="{ group, items, isOpen, toggle, remove }">
        <td colspan="2">
            <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
              <v-icon v-if="isOpen">
                mdi-minus
              </v-icon>
              <v-icon v-else>
                mdi-plus
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            Category: {{ group }} {{ items.length }}
            <v-btn icon @click="remove">
              <v-icon>
                mdi-close
            </v-btn>
        </td>
 </template>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/6EiVrQkR7s)

Comment: Perfect. Is there any documentation or a way to find supported slots. I was not able to find this slot in the official `v-data-table` documentation.